# Sort SQLite database by a parameter

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database with tow parameters one is a string called app_name the other one is an integer of how many times the app was opened.
After running the code

```
 String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_OPENED};
    Cursor c = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    String result = "";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iAppName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iTimesOpened = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPENED);
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result = result+c.getString(iRow)+" "+c.getString(iAppName)+" //"+c.getString(iTimesOpened)+"\n";
    }
    return result;
```

result equals:

1 dialer 1

2 whatsapp 7

3 facebook 20

4 google play store 10

I want the result to be sorted by the times opened so it will look like this

1 facebook 20

2 google play store 10

3 whatsapp 7

4 dialer 1

How can i change that order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor c = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null, KEY_OPENED);
```

The last parameter to query is ORDER BY.

If you want to order by the integer value of the `KEY_OPENED` column, you can use `CAST` operator to cast the value of the field into an integer.

```
Cursor c = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null, "CAST( " + KEY_OPENED + " AS INTEGER)");
```

Comment: It works but it orders it like this
for example
1
11
2
22
3
as if 3 is bigger than 22 because it get it as a string,how can i use it like an integer ?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 Cursor c = scoreDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, rank, null, null, null, null, yourColumn+" DESC");
```

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) documentation to understand more about query method.

Comment: It works but it orders it like this for example 1 11 2 22 3 as if 3 is bigger than 22 because it get it as a string,how can i use it like an integer ?